# d3.js v5 update data on filter returning cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling with updating a d3.js chart off a selection filter. Everything runs and loads the data on the first run through, however when the filter is selected and the update element runs for the second time the console.log(data) inside the update function returns undefined. I've searched and I can't understand why this is happening? The idea is that I will be able to add the following to filter the data and then add new data elements and remove old. I've stripped everything back to try to understand what is happening but I've got to the point where I can spot the error:

```
var data = data.filter(function(d){
        if (survey == "all") { return true; }
        else {
            return d.name == survey;
        }
    })
```

The data is in a very basic format which matches the selection drop down.

Name, Value

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left:200}
var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#graphic_two").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
var g =  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var time = 0;
var data;

// Set the X Label
var xLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "x label")
    .attr("y", height + 50)
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("font-size", "15px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Topic Count");

// Set the Y Label
var yLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y axisLabel")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -(120))
    .attr("x", -350)
    .attr("font-size", "15px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Topic Names")



d3.json(topicData).then(function(data){
    //console.log(data);

    update(data)
})

$("#survey")
    .on("change", function(){
        update(data);
    })


function step(){
    // At the end of our data, loop back
    time = (time < 214) ? time+1 : 0
    update(data);
}


function update(data) {
    console.log("I'm in the update function")




    var survey = $("#survey").val();
    console.log(survey);
    console.log(data)


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>



<select id="survey" data-placeholder="Select a survey type..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="3">
  <option selected value="all">All</option>
  <option value="Vehicle - Poor">Vehicle - Poor</option>
  <option value="Problems - Unresolved">Problems - Unresolved</option>
  <option value="Reliability - Poor">Reliability - Poor</option>
</select>


<div id="graphic_two"></div>
```

Comment: You are using same variable `data` on right-handside in assigning a variable `var data = data.filter....`

Comment: I tweaked the variable names and got it working. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @MaheerAli how is that a problem?

Comment: @Woody_1983 `data` is only accessible inside the `then` method.